# Turing Machine for $\{w\# w ' |$ where $w < w'$ lexicographically, and $w,w'\in \{0,1\}^* \}$

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines, automata, binary, comparison

I am blocked with this question for a long time.

$L = \{w\# w ' |$  where $w < w'$ lexicographically, and $w,w'\in \{0,1\}^* \}$

I am trying to find

1. A Deterministic Turing Machine for L.
2. A Non-Deterministic Turing Machine for L.

**Example**

- $01\#111 \in L$ since $ w=01$  and $w=111$   and $01 < 111$
- $1\#011 \notin L$ since $ w=1$  and $w=011$   but $1 \not< 011$

For the deterministic TM, I have an idea only when $|w|=|w'|$, it's only comparing $i^{th}$ symbol in the first string with $i^{th}$ symbol in the second string, but I don't know how to solve it when we have two different length.

Please help me in solving this.

**Note**
$w<w'$ lexicographically. As example, $0<1<00<01<000<001.........$
When length of string are same, we compare their $ASCII$ Value $(0<1)$, from Left to Right $(00<01)$, else string of shorter length is always less than large one $(1<000)$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sketch of a construction method of the TM:

- Compare bit by bit from the first bit to the last bit as normal. If equals, proceed to the next bit. Otherwise, it can decide the order.
- If the head of TM reaches the word separator $\#$ or the blank symbol (say $\$$ or something), finish the comparison. If both words end simultaneously (i.e. when $\left| w \right| = \left| w' \right|$), then $w = w'$. If not, the shorter word is less than the other in the lexicographic order.

This idea is the same for both a deterministic TM and a non-deterministic TM. Only a non-deterministic TM can compare bits in a non-deterministic way.

Answer (score -1):

First, you can compute $|w|$ and $|w'|$. For the minimum between of them, proceed with your algorithm, comparing bit by bit. If they equal for all the bits, the longer one is the "greater" and then you can decide if the given word belongs to $L$.